# Кастомизация формы в Django

Tags: python, django

Есть предварительная форма подачи данных для компаний, которые хотят в будущем получить бесплатный доступ к онлайн платформе.
Я создал модель для базы данных, далее форму и добавил это во вьюшку. И вроде все нормально, форма отправляется и данные попадают в базу, создается профиль с данными о компаниях, но есть одна проблема, я хочу что бы шаблон с этой формой работал с той версткой которую мне скинули. А у меня, к сожалению, получается так что работает форма только если укажу {{ form.as_p }} (соответственно на стандартных не кастомизированных полях).

Как выглядит models.py

```
class BusinessType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-title',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    agent_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    company_description = models.TextField()
    email_adress =  models.EmailField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    business_type = models.ForeignKey(BusinessType, related_name='company_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='Form/Logo/', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-company_name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

    def get_absolute_url(self): # перенаправляем пользователя на страницу благодарности
        return reverse('Form:success_page')
```

Вот так выглядит views.py:

```
def home(request):
return render(request, 'main.html')

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html')

class RequestFormView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'request.html'
    model = Company
    fields = ('company_name', 'agent_name', 'company_address', 'company_description', 'email_adress', 'phone_number', 'business_type', 'logo')
```

И вот так выглядит шаблон request.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="agent_name"><h6 class="">Your Name</h6></label>
            <div class="form-group field-agent_name">
              <input class="form-control" input id="agent_name" name="agent_name" placeholder="Your Name">
            </div>
            >
            <label for="company_name"><h6 class="">Company Name</h6></label>
            <div class="form-group field-company_name">
              <input class="form-control" input id="company_name" name="company_name" placeholder="Company">
            </div>

            <label for="company_address"><h6 class="">Address</h6></label>
            <div class="form-group field-company_address">
              <input class="form-control" input id="company_address" name="company_address" placeholder="Company Address">
            </div>

            <label for="company_description"><h6 class="">Company Description:</h6></label>
            <div class="form-group field-company_description">
              <textarea class="form-control" input id="company_description" name="company_description" placeholder="Company Description:"></textarea>
            </div>

            <label for="email_adress"><h6 class="">E-mail Address</h6></label>
            <div class="form-group field-email_adress">
              <input class="form-control" input id="email_adress" name="email_adress" placeholder="E-mail Address">
            </div>

            <label for="phone_number"><h6 class="">Phone Number</h6></label>
            <div class="form-group field-phone_number">
              <input class="form-control" input id="phone_number" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number">
            </div>

            <label for="business_type"><h6 class="">Type of Business</h6></label>
            <div class="form-group field-business_type">
              <select class="form-control" select id="business_type" name="business_type">
                <option>Individual</option>
                <option>Salon</option>
              </select>
            </div>
           
            <label for="logo"><h6 class="">Upload Your Logo Here:</h6></label>
            <div class="custom-file field-logo">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="logo" id="logo">
              <label class="logo" for="logo">Choose file</label>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-twitter" style="width: 100%;background-color: #007BFF;border-color: #007BFF;">Register</button>
            {% csrf_token %} 
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Подскажите, плиз, как сделать так что бы те поля которые уже сверстаны в шаблоне **request.html** принимали те данные которые мне нужны? ( что бы **не использовать** **{{ form.as_p }}** )

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вы можете сверстать форму вручную, используя теги django templates. Например, как описано вот тут https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html